# Why does IO.Compression.ZipFile count of Entries not match 7zip GUI?

Tags: powershell, zip, system.io.compression

I'm trying to verify the contents of a ZIP archive in PowerShell by counting the number of zipped entries like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643218/count-files-and-folders-in-a-zip-file-using-powershell) answer.

However, the results are inconsistent between 7Zip GUI, gci, Entries.Count and 7Zip CLI, for example:

```
(Get-ChildItem -path $sourceFolder -Recurse | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }).Count
```

= 77779 files

```
[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipFile).Entries.Count
```

= 77838 entries

```
&'c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' l $zipFile
```

= 77779 files, 59 folders (i.e. 77838 objects)

However the 59 folder count is wrong - the 7Zip GUI shows 77779 files and 35726 folders.

Is there a way to exclude folders from .Entries?  Otherwise I could parse out the results from 7z.exe l command like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643218/count-files-and-folders-in-a-zip-file-using-powershell), but would prefer the native approach

Comment: when you unzip each to new dirs, what do you observe?  compare the 2 with beyond compare or such...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a custom count... If the entry only specifies a folder, skip it:

```
($zip.entries.where({!$_.FullName.EndsWith('/')})).count
```

Comment: Thank you - I wasn't aware the directory entries ended with '/', but that makes total sense